# mySQL RDS Table Data import wizard using csv file

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I try to import data from a CSV using for a particular table, the wizard runs successfully but imports only 558 records when the csv has around 15882 rows. How do I find the root cause for this behavior?

I tried the data import in another instance of the mySQL AWS RDS and there all of the 15882 rows got inserted.

How do i figure out the root cause for this behavior?

Comment: Are you trying to use MySQL Workbench to do the import? See my answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/318182/progressbar-error-and-very-slow-import-in-mysql/318200#318200

Comment: I am using mySQL workbench to do the import. In my case, i dont see any error but it did finish the import after few minutes (509 seconds). But it only imported 558+ records and not the whole 15882. I did the same exercise in another server (mySQL) and there it imported all of them successfully. Is it to do with any restrictions with mySQL privileges?

Comment: No, it's likely because MySQL Workbench has bugs and badly designed code. I don't use it. I recommend you do your import using the tools that do work.